# shower wall jets replacement

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

One of our old wall mount jets in the shower broke. The pipe got rusted. The plumbing suppliers do not sell this kind of wall shower jets in California because of regulations. I am wondering if I can get it from outside of the state of California, and how would one go about it.

Here are the pictures of that shower jet. I can provide more details if required.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Every home shower head ( and tub spout) I have seen in the midwest has been 1/2 " NPT . The threads in the picture look too fine ( more threads per inch. I would try any piece of 1/2 " NPT  to evaluate it.

Comment: By any chance, do you know any store online I can try to find a match to this one?

Comment: Are there any markings on it or on the main showerhead or valve that would indicate the brand?  That would be the best place to start.

Comment: I think it is this one: https://picclick.com/Antique-Vintage-American-Standard-Shower-Valve-w-Body-Spray-232402027443.html#&gid=1&pid=5